# MPS Pytorch Error when running Model Summary

Tags: python, pytorch, apple-silicon, metal-performance-shaders

When running the following cell I obtain this error:
slow_conv2d_forward_mps: input(device='cpu') and weight(device=mps:0')  must be on the same device

The code runs correctly when model = Net().to(cps) is run.

I cannot seem to find where to change input(device='cpu') to input(device='mps')

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        # Input Block
        self.convblock1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=8, kernel_size=(3, 3),padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU(),
            #nn.BatchNorm2d(4)
        )
        self.pool11 = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        # CONVOLUTION BLOCK
        self.convblock2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=8, out_channels=16, kernel_size=(3, 3),padding=0,bias=False),
            nn.ReLU(),
            #nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
        )
        # TRANSITION BLOCK
        self.pool22 = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.convblock3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=10, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding=0,bias=False),
            #nn.BatchNorm2d(10),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        self.pool33 = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        # CONVOLUTION BLOCK
        self.convblock4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=10, out_channels=10, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU(),
            #nn.BatchNorm2d(10)
        )
        self.convblock5 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=10, out_channels=32, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding=0, bias=False),
            #nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.ReLU(),
        )
        self.convblock6 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=10, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU(),
            #nn.BatchNorm2d(10),
        )
        self.convblock7 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=10, out_channels=10, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU(),
            #nn.BatchNorm2d(10)
        )
        self.convblock8 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=10, out_channels=32, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding=0, bias=False),
            #nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.ReLU()
        )
        self.convblock9 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=10, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU(),
            #nn.BatchNorm2d(10),
        )
        self.convblock10 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=10, out_channels=14, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU(),
            #nn.BatchNorm2d(14),
        )
        self.convblock11 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=14, out_channels=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU(),
        #nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
        )
        # OUTPUT BLOCK
        self.gap = nn.Sequential(
            nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=4)
        )
        self.convblockout = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=2, kernel_size=(4, 4), padding=0, bias=False),
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.convblock1(x)
        x = self.pool11(x)
        x = self.convblock2(x)
        x = self.pool22(x)
        x = self.convblock3(x)
        x = self.pool33(x)
        x = self.convblock4(x)
        x = self.convblock5(x)
        x = self.convblock6(x)
        x = self.convblock7(x)
        x = self.convblock8(x)
        x = self.convblock9(x)
        x = self.convblock10(x)
        x = self.convblock11(x)
        x = self.gap(x)
        x = self.convblockout(x)
        x = x.view(-1, 2)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=-1)

    
    mps = torch.device("mps")
    cpu = torch.device("cpu")
    model = Net().to(mps)
    summary(model, input_size=(3, 224, 224))
```

I have tried changing the blocks to .to(mps)

`self.convblock1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=8, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=0, bias=False),nn.ReLU()).to(mps)` 
I dont know if I need to change the data itself to .to(mps)

Comment: you forgot to indent the class constructor `__init__()`

Comment: presumably also `def forward` should be indented into the class....  (indentation matters since it provides scope).

Answer (score 0):

I found putting the input to device resolve the problem.

```
device=torch.device('mps')


def forward(self, x):
        x=x.to(device)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A new feature that helps a lot with simple bugs like this is

`torch.set_default_device("mps")` that way won't need those `to()` calls in your code

Read more here https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.set_default_device.html